# Struct method type inference

Tags: rust

Given the following:

```
use std::old_io::{BufferedReader, File};

struct Journal<T> where T: Buffer {
    file: T,
}

impl<T: Buffer> Iterator for Journal<T> {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        match self.file.read_line() {
            Ok(line) => Some(line.to_string()),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("/tmp/allocator-journal.txt");
    let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(&path));

    let journal = Journal {file: file};
    for line in journal {
        print!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

I would like to move the file opening logic into a `new` method on Journal. The following fails to compile due to `unable to infer enough type information about '_'; type annotations required [E0282]`:

```
use std::old_io::{BufferedReader, File, IoResult};

struct Journal<T> where T: Buffer {
    file: T,
}

impl<T: Buffer> Journal<T> {
    fn new() -> Journal<BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>> {
        let path = Path::new("/tmp/allocator-journal.txt");
        let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(&path));
        Journal {file: file}
    }
}

impl<T: Buffer> Iterator for Journal<T> {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        match self.file.read_line() {
            Ok(line) => Some(line.to_string()),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let journal = Journal::new();
    for line in journal {
        print!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

Neither adding type hints to the variable binding or the method call (`Journal::new::<Journal<BufferedReader<etc..>>>`) fix the problem.

Why can the type not be infered? The signature of Journal::new is explicit, right?

As an aside, why can't the return type of `Journal::new()` be `Journal<T>` where T = Buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the worlds of generics and not-generics (specifics?). Here's the fix:

```
impl Journal<BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>> {
    fn new() -> Journal<BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>> {
        let path = Path::new("/tmp/allocator-journal.txt");
        let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(&path));
        Journal {file: file}
    }
}
```

Note the lack of `T` here. The whole point is that you are deciding what type `T` must be (`BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>`), so there's no need for the type variable.

By *having* the type variable, the compiler is attempting to figure out what `T` should be. However, you don't use `T` anywhere, so it has nothing to connect the dots with, and you get an error stating as much.

This brings up the question: *why have generics at all?* You aren't actually using them for anything, so you might as well just replace `T` with `BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>` everywhere.